# How to save jQuery Get response to React variable?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

How do I save `response.status` from `$.get()` into a React variable `this.posts`?

When I try to access `this.posts` from within `$.get()` it returns `undefined`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class MediumPosts extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.posts = [];
  }

  fetchPosts = () => {
    var data = {
      rss_url: 'https://medium.com/feed/tradecraft-traction'
    };
    $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, (response) => {
      if (response.status == 'ok') {
        console.log(response.items);
        this.posts = response.items; // Undefined
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.posts.map(function(item, i) {
          return (
            <li key={item.guid}>
              <h4>{item.title}</h4>
              <time>{item.pubDate}</time>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default MediumPosts;
```

Comment: I recommend you to use fetch to make network calls in react and create a state to save the response.

Comment: You should learn about component's state in react. See [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) from the redux docs.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should keep your `posts` in state.

When value is changes over the time it should be in the `state` (if it's not coming from the parent component) and then you just need update it.

[ReactJS docs reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

So, your code will look like:

```
class MediumPosts extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // init state
    this.state = {
        posts: [],
    }
  }

  fetchPosts = () => {
    // because you are pass arrow function in the callback we have to save `this`.
    // or you can create callback function in the component and pass it
    const self = this;
    const data = {
      rss_url: 'https://medium.com/feed/tradecraft-traction'
    };

    $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, response => {
      if (response.status == 'ok') {
        self.setState({posts: response.items});
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.posts.map(function(item, i) {
          return (
            <li key={item.guid}>
              <h4>{item.title}</h4>
              <time>{item.pubDate}</time>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default MediumPosts;
```

Anyway, I advice you to get rid of `jQuery` in ReactJS projects. Instead, use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Hope it will helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I'll try to upgrade to using axios.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem - mark as Solved - it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.proxy()` to use a particular context.

```
$.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, $.proxy(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'ok') {
        console.log(response.items);
        this.posts = response.items; // Undefined
    }
}, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  fetchPosts = () => {
    var self=this;
        var data = {
          rss_url: 'https://medium.com/feed/tradecraft-traction'
        };
        $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, (response) => {
          if (response.status == 'ok') {
            console.log(response.items);
            self.setState({posts:response.items});
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try for callback -

```
var callback = function(value)
{
this.posts = value;  //check here weather this is accessible or not otherwise use var self = this
} 

 $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, (response,callback) => {
      if (response.status == 'ok') {
        console.log(response.items);
        this.posts = response.items; // Undefined
    callback(response.items);
      }
    });
```